# python code to split into multiple nested list

Tags: python

I am having the following input data(temp_list1). I am trying to convert this input into a nested list as mentioned below(new_list).
this input is part of vnstat command's output.

Input:

> temp_list1 = [(' eno1:', "\r\n       Oct '19     10.09 GiB  /   68.98 GiB  /   79.08 GiB  /  164.53 GiB\r\n     yesterday      1.11 GiB  /    7.35 GiB  /    8.46 GiB\r\n         today    432.51 MiB  /    4.22 GiB  /    4.65 GiB  /    7.17 GiB\r\n\r"), (' eno5:', "\r\n       Oct '19     18.82 TiB  /   18.39 TiB  /   37.21 TiB  /   77.43 TiB\r\n     yesterday      2.65 TiB  /    2.59 TiB  /    5.24 TiB\r\n         today      1.95 TiB  /    1.90 TiB  /    3.85 TiB  /    5.95 TiB\r\n\r\n")]

Expected output:

```
new_list[ ['eno1',["Oct '19",'10.09 GiB','68.98 GiB','79.08 GiB','164.53 GiB'],
                  ["yesterday",'1.11 GiB','7.35 GiB','8.46 GiB'],
                  ["today",'432.51 MiB','4.22 GiB','4.65 GiB','7.17 GiB]
          ],
          ['eno5',["Oct '19",'18.82 TiB','18.39 TiB','37.21 TiB','77.43 TiB'],
                  ["yesterday",'2.65 TiB','2.59 TiB','5.24 TiB'],
                  ["today",'1.95 TiB','1.90 TiB','3.85 TiB','5.95 TiB']
          ]
        ]
```

I am trying to split the input data using the python code but do not know how to do it.

```
 temp_list2 = []
 temp_list1 = [(' eno1:', "\r\n       Oct '19     10.09 GiB  /   68.98 GiB  /   79.08 GiB  /  164.53 GiB\r\n     yesterday      1.11 GiB  /    7.35 GiB  /    8.46 GiB\r\n         today    432.51 MiB  /    4.22 GiB  /    4.65 GiB  /    7.17 GiB\r\n\r"), (' eno5:', "\r\n       Oct '19     18.82 TiB  /   18.39 TiB  /   37.21 TiB  /   77.43 TiB\r\n     yesterday      2.65 TiB  /    2.59 TiB  /    5.24 TiB\r\n         today      1.95 TiB  /    1.90 TiB  /    3.85 TiB  /    5.95 TiB\r\n\r\n")]

 for i in temp_list1:
   temp_list2.append i.split('?')
 print (temp_list2)
```

Comment: Please fix the input, It's confusing to see the format change repeatedly.

Comment: Can you share the code for creating temp_list1 in the first place? It may be easier to construct your desired output directly from the vnstat subprocess stdout rather than creating temp_list1.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that vnStat has also a json format output available with `vnstat --json` which would eliminate the need for this kind of string parsing if the target is to gain access to the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
temp_list1 = [(' eno1:', "\r\n Oct '19 10.09 GiB / 68.98 GiB / 79.08 GiB / 164.53 GiB\r\n yesterday 1.11 GiB / 7.35 GiB / 8.46 GiB\r\n today 432.51 MiB / 4.22 GiB / 4.65 GiB / 7.17 GiB\r\n\r"), 
              (' eno5:', "\r\n Oct '19 18.82 TiB / 18.39 TiB / 37.21 TiB / 77.43 TiB\r\n yesterday 2.65 TiB / 2.59 TiB / 5.24 TiB\r\n today 1.95 TiB / 1.90 TiB / 3.85 TiB / 5.95 TiB\r\n\r\n")]


new_list =[ [ b[0].strip(), [ c.strip().split(" / ") for c in b[1] if c.strip() ]] 
        for b in [[a[0], a[1].split("\r\n")] 
            for a in temp_list1] ]

for a in new_list:
    for b in a[1]:
        x = b[0].replace(" '", "'").split()
        b[0:1] = [x[0].replace("'", " '"), ' '.join(x[1:])]

print ( new_list)


#Result:
# [
#    [ 'eno1:',[
#          [ "Oct '19", '10.09 GiB', '68.98 GiB', '79.08 GiB', '164.53 GiB'],
#          [ 'yesterday', '1.11 GiB', '7.35 GiB', '8.46 GiB'],
#          [ 'today', '432.51 MiB', '4.22 GiB', '4.65 GiB', '7.17 GiB']
#       ]
#    ],
#    [ 'eno5:',[
#          [ "Oct '19", '18.82 TiB', '18.39 TiB', '37.21 TiB', '77.43 TiB'],
#          [ 'yesterday', '2.65 TiB', '2.59 TiB', '5.24 TiB'],
#          [ 'today', '1.95 TiB', '1.90 TiB', '3.85 TiB', '5.95 TiB']
#       ]
#    ]
# ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a dict comprehension that makes use of `re`

```
data = temp_list1 = [(' eno1:', "\r\n       Oct '19     10.09 GiB  /   68.98 GiB  /   79.08 GiB  /  164.53 GiB\r\n     yesterday      1.11 GiB  /    7.35 GiB  /    8.46 GiB\r\n         today    432.51 MiB  /    4.22 GiB  /    4.65 GiB  /    7.17 GiB\r\n\r"), (' eno5:', "\r\n       Oct '19     18.82 TiB  /   18.39 TiB  /   37.21 TiB  /   77.43 TiB\r\n     yesterday      2.65 TiB  /    2.59 TiB  /    5.24 TiB\r\n         today      1.95 TiB  /    1.90 TiB  /    3.85 TiB  /    5.95 TiB\r\n\r\n")]

new = {re.search('\w+', k)[0]: re.findall('\S+ \S+|\w+', v) for k, v in data}
```

Results:

```
{'eno1': ["Oct '19", '10.09 GiB', '68.98 GiB', '79.08 GiB', '164.53 GiB', 'yesterday', '1.11 GiB', '7.35 GiB', '8.46 GiB', 'today', '432.51 MiB', '4.22 GiB', '4.65 GiB', '7.17 GiB'],
 'eno5': ["Oct '19", '18.82 TiB', '18.39 TiB', '37.21 TiB', '77.43 TiB', 'yesterday', '2.65 TiB', '2.59 TiB', '5.24 TiB', 'today', '1.95 TiB', '1.90 TiB', '3.85 TiB', '5.95 TiB']}
```

Comment: He wanted whole quarter as one value. For example "Oct '19". It is getting split in your answer.

Comment: I fixed that using `re`

Comment: I have tried the same code but getting error 
temp_list2 = {re.search('\w+', k)[0]: re.findall('\S+ \S+|\w+', v) for k, v in temp_list1}          
TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object is not subscriptable  

code: 
import re
temp_list2 = {re.search('\w+', k)[0]: re.findall('\S+ \S+|\w+', v) for k, v in temp_list1}
print (temp_list2)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simplify your code, you can use the `--dumpdb` option of vnstat.
It is explained [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/11/vnstat-network-traffic-monitor/).

vnstat has also other option to format the output, like `vnstat --json` or `vnstat --xml`.
The `--json` one can be usefull along with the tool `jq` to convert the output to your exact need.

For example,

```
vnstat --json | jq '.interfaces[] | select(.id == "eth0") | .traffic | .days[1] | .rx'
```

will extract the number of kiB received on the interface `eth0` yesterday (the day `0` is today, `1` is yesterday, etc)

You can sum the rx and tx with :

```
vnstat --json | jq '.interfaces[] | select(.id == "eth0") | .traffic | .days[1] | .rx+.tx'
```

You can also sum several days, for example today and yesterday :

```
vnstat --json | jq '.interfaces[] | select(.id == "eth0") | .traffic | [.days[0,1] | .rx+.tx] | add'
```

And instead of days, you can references "months" or "hours" (for `hours`, be careful, the id has not the same meaning, it's the reference of the hour).